# Python: Certain unicode characters do not display correctly

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, fonts

I am trying to set the label of a GUI-element to display a greek letter with Python.

`str(u'\u0054'.encode('utf8'))`
will correctly produce the unicode character 'T', as its unicode number is 0054.

Writing
`str(u'\u03B6'.encode('utf8'))`
will not display the Greek letter small zeta but [this](https://snag.gy/YsG0CP.jpg) thing instead.

I tried writing
`str(u'\uceb6'.encode('utf8'))` as well (ceb6 is the utf-8 encoding of the character I want), but got a similar, strange looking character that certainly wasn't the Greek letter zeta.

According to [this](http://www.htmlescape.net/03/character_greek_small_letter_zeta_03b6.html) site the character is available in common fonts.

Might it be that the GUI-toolkit uses a strange font? I am using the FOX toolkit.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:
I am specifically trying to create a text label `FXLabel(parent, string)` where i supply the string `str(u'\u03B6'.encode('utf8'))`. And as mentioned, supplying the string with the unicode number of capital t will produce the expected label.

Comment: The character `T`, encoded as a UTF8 string, looks like this: `T`. However, the character `ζ` as a UTF8 string is this: `Î¶`, that is, the characters `0xCE` and `0xB6` in an arbitrary code page (this one is Latin-1). Which is what you got, so the problem lies not in encoding but in what your library expects.

Comment: .. By the way, your quote "available in most fonts" is far from what is actually said: "Supported in all common fonts". The 'common fonts' under that remark are the so-called 'web safe fonts', "likely to be present on a wide range of computer systems" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_typography#Web-safe_fonts). Unless you don't have a lot of fonts, this is a **very** small subset of 'most fonts'.

Comment: @RadLexus Thanks, so I should find which numbers correspond to the character I want in Latin-1? I just find it strange that it interprets the encoding of T as one single character while in the second case it breaks it up into two parts. Oh and I edited my question :)

Comment: @RadLexus I found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195054.aspx) link showing the codes for the latin-1 localization. There isn't much. Can I somehow specify to look for Unicode numbers and not numbers in an arbitrary code page?

Comment: You may need to brush up on what "UTF8" actually *means*. In Python (and in other programming languages as well), a `character` cannot hold any arbitrary value but is typically restricted to a range of `0` to `255`. "UTF8" is a way circumvent this and to store many more code points; it does necessarily do so by using more than a single character.

Answer (score 0):

Your output encoding is wrong. Make sure your terminal is correctly configured for UTF-8 output.

If I interpret your (rather muddy) image correctly, CE B6 is being displayed as 
Î‎¶‎ which is consistent with any one of a number of common Western [8-bit encodings](https://rawgit.com/tripleee/8bit/master/encodings.html).

Comment: Yes, that is the character(s) that are outputted. What do you mean by configuring my terminal for UTF-8 output? As to the link you supplied, I am not exactly sure of what I am looking at. How do I know which localization to use, and why does Python interpret my unicode number as two characters with two hexadecimal numbers each instead of one character with four hexadecimal numbers?

Comment: UTF-8 encodes this character as two bytes. You need to configure your environment (basically, the program from which you run Python) to interpret this output correctly. This is a common FAQ; you should easily find instructions for your environment, )ut your question lacks the details to tell you anything specific.